# Drawing Axes on top of a Grid of plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing, grid-layouts

I have a grid of density plots, for example like this toy example

```
plots = Table[DensityPlot[Cos[2 \[Pi] (n x^2 + m y^2)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> 150, PlotPoints -> 20], {n, -2, 2}, {m, -2, 2}];
plotgrid = Grid[plots, Frame -> All]
```

I want to add axes on top of the grid so it looks something like this

[image]

The problem is that the `Grid` is not a `Graphics` object, so my naive attempt didn't work, e.g. this gives an error:

```
Show[plotgrid, Graphics@Arrow@{Scaled[{-0.1, 0.5}], Scaled[{1.1, 0.5}]}]
```

Is there some simple way to treat the entire `Grid` object as a graphics object, or other solution to drawing axes or other `Graphics` objects on top of the `Grid`?

Comment: Unlike `Grid`, [`GraphicsGrid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html) returns a graphics object.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I'm aware of that, unfortunately `GraphicsGrid` has a known bug where it doesn't play nicely with `PlotLegends` :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`Rasterize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) `Grid[plots]` and use it with [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) as [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) in `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[MapThread[{AbsoluteThickness[3], #, Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[#2]} &, 
  {{Red, Green, Blue}, 
   {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1/2}, {1, 1/2}}, {{1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1}}}}], 
  Prolog -> Inset[Rasterize[Grid[plots, Frame -> All]], Automatic, Automatic, 1], 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Use `.9` instead of `1` in the last argument of `Inset[...]` to get

[image]

Comment: This is the solution I wound up going with, although rasterizing is really not ideal unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "Overlay" but the result is more a "hack" and not really satisfying:

```
dx = 1; dy = 1;
axes = Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], Red, Arrow[{{-dx, 0}, {dx, 0}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, -dy}, {0, dy}}], Green, 
    Arrow[{{-dx, -0.95 dy}, {dx, 0.95 dy}}], 
    Text[Style["X", Red, Large], {0.95 dx, 0.05}], 
    Text[Style["Y", Red, Large], {0.050, 0.95 dy}], 
    Text[Style["Y=X", Green, Large], {0.85 dx, 0.95 dy}]}, 
   ImageSize -> {850, 740}, PlotRange -> {{-0.9, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
Overlay[{plotgrid, axes}]
```

[image]